# React Router programatically navigate to route

Tags: javascript, react-router

I have some constant:

```
const routes = {
    route1: '/route-1'
};

<Switch>
    <Route exact path={`${routes.route1}/:id`} component={SomeComponent}>
</Switch>
```

Then I want to navigate from another component, so I do:

```
history.push(`${routes.route1}/${myId}`);
```

Is this right?

Or should I do this:

```
history.push(routes.route1, { id: myId });
```

Cause this second one is not working

Comment: react-router has a [redirect](https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Redirect) component for this

Comment: The second doesn't work because it's not compatible to the `history.push` api. Ref: https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/master/docs/api-reference.md#history.push and https://github.com/ReactTraining/history/blob/master/docs/navigation.md

Comment: @Reyno but I wan't to navigate coming from an onclick event, programatically, not declarative

Comment: @Yoshi so you can push state that's hidden from the URL, but params you should pass in the URL itself right?

Comment: I'd say so, yes.

Answer (score 0):

The first one is correct. The second one actually specified a `state` for the route. So in the navigated page, you will find that `id` under `state` where state is derived from:

`const { state: { id } } = useLocation();`

The first one will give your the parameter `id` from:

`const { id } = useParams();`

`useParams()` and `useLocation()` are hooks your can use on your components;